# pandas: Grouping or filtering based on values in list, instead of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get a row count of the frequency of each value, even if that value doesn't exist in the dataframe.

```
d = {'light' : pd.Series(['b','b','c','a','a','a','a'], index=[1,2,3,4,5,6,9]),'injury' : pd.Series([1,5,5,5,2,2,4], index=[1,2,3,4,5,6,9])}

testdf = pd.DataFrame(d)

   injury light
1       1     b
2       5     b
3       5     c
4       5     a
5       2     a
6       2     a
9       4     a
```

I want to get a count of the number of occurrences of each unique value of 'injury' for each unique value in 'light'.

Normally I would just use `groupby()`, or (in this case, since I want it to be in a specific format), `pivot_table:`

```
testdf.reset_index().pivot_table(index='light',columns='injury',fill_value=0,aggfunc='count')

       index         
injury     1  2  4  5
light                
a          0  2  1  1
b          1  0  0  1
c          0  0  0  1
```

But in this case I actually want to compare the records in the dataframe to an external list of values-- in this case, `['a','b','c','d']`. So if 'd' doesn't exist in this dataframe, then I want it to return a count of zero:

```
       index         
injury     1  2  4  5
light                
a          0  2  1  1
b          1  0  0  1
c          0  0  0  1
d          0  0  0  0
```

The closest I've come is filtering the dataframe based on each value, and then getting the size of that dataframe:

```
for v in sorted(['a','b','c','d']):
    idx2 = (df['light'].isin([v]))
    df2 = df[idx2]
    print(df2.shape[0])

4
2
1
0
```

But that only returns counts from the 'light' column-- instead of a cross-tabulation of both columns.

Is there a way to make a pivot table, or a `groupby()` object, that groups things based on values in a list, rather than in a column in a dataframe? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df.light, df.injury,margins=True)
df

injury  1   2   4   5   All
light                   
a      0    2   1   1   4
b      1    0   0   1   2
c      0    0   0   1   1
All    1    2   1   3   7

df["All"]

light
a      4
b      2
c      1
All    7
```

Comment: That doesn't work. My question asks about comparing the dataframe to a list of existing values. It should include a row of zeroes if 'd' does not exist in the 'light' column. Yours does not include 'd'. See my desired output above (the second to last code section).